# Eclipse: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl

Tags: android, eclipse, facebook, dex

A similar question has been asked for Android Studio. But I am an eclipse user.

I am including the Facebook SDK in my project. After adding the SDK, when I run the program, I get the error

`Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl`

I tried cleaning and the error persists. Any ideas how to solve this issue? Again, I am using eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

This really should be just a warning that won't stop your compilation. I believe by default it will use the most recent version of the file in the path of your project.  Since the facebook API might be a version behind the recent released version included in your project, you can either remove your version in the project and rely on theirs, ignore the warning or update them so they both have the same version of the compatibility library.

Comment: Actually it's keeping my code from compiling, so it's not just a warning. 2) When I removed my `appcompat_v7`, my project went all red with errors even after I cleaned. 3) I tried unchecking the `Android Private Libraries` in the build path: this caused my app to crash before showing anything.

Comment: Also I tried removing either support library and that didn't help.